# Find the selection range indices on raw HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to find out how to get the indices that defines a selection substring on raw HTML. I know that when you select a text it's possible to get information about it using `window.getSelection` or `document.selection`. However, I was not able to use that for my purposes.

Here a simple example, consider the following HTML:

```
<body><div>selected text</div></body>
```

If I select the text `selected text`, I want to get the pair `[12, 24]` that defines the range of the selection on the raw HTML of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Search selected element. Add the flag to the parent element. Take the data.
Set them and remove the flag. Show the result on console.

```
var selObj    = window.getSelection(); // Get info from selected text
var selectionBind = selObj.extentNode.parentElement; // find the nearest container to bind the flag
var nameBinding = 'data_bind'; // Name of the flag that we want to find 
selectionBind.setAttribute(nameBinding,''); // Set the flag on that selected element
var text      = selObj.anchorNode.data; // Get text from selected text
var selRange  = selObj.getRangeAt(0);

var offsetEnd = selRange.endOffset; // How long selected text was

var selected  = text.substring(0, offsetEnd); // Prepare only the selected text

var body   = document.body // Take all the body

var string = body.outerHTML; // Set them to line of string

var selectedBegin = string.search(nameBinding); // Find the text you selected on that string begin offset

var selectedEnd   = selectedBegin + offsetEnd - 1; // Value of the end of that selected text
selectionBind.removeAttribute(nameBinding); // Remove the flag
var data = [selectedBegin,selectedEnd];
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution just works to get the first occurrence of the selection. Would be great to have a solution that returns the exact occurrence of the selection.

Comment: Yes. That was write to you to show how you could start to find that element.
I made the flag update to show exactly the element you want to find ;)